# Convert double into BigRational (two BigInteger for numerator/denominator)

Tags: java

I have a custom made BigRational class in java.
It is implemented as two BigInteger, representing numerator and denominator.

I have a "from string" method that take input in the form "-1234/43"
but I would like to implement a from double/from float;
I'm not scare of generating a very large number, but I would like to keep all the precision present in the floating point representation; thus if I converted them in some decimal representation I would lose precision thanks to rounding.

-How do I generate a pair of BigIntegers that interpreted as numerator/denominator represents the same exact number as a given float/double?

(Hopefully by being in Java I do not need to worry about bigendian/littleendian, but I would like a confermation too)

Comment: Are you going to add a method that takes ONE float and creates your BigRational?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51142275/exact-value-of-a-floating-point-number-as-a-rational

Comment: yes, one method that takes a double and produces a BigRational.
I'm searching for an elegant way using java standard library features

Comment: I see. From the question liked above I understand there is no java standard method for solving this. Probably because is a complex mathematical problem and not usually needed in day to day programming. Maybe google for know algorithms that solve this and implement your version of one you like.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to a good friend I have found a good solution, so I will post it here for anyone in need.
It is not using any string representation so it should also be quite on the fast side.
I have tested it "reasonably" and It seams to work and to keep the exact representation.
Of course, we should still add some 'if' to handle NANs.

```
final static int mantissaBits=53;
public static BigRational from(double num){
  int exponent=Math.getExponent(num);
  long man=Math.round(Math.scalb(num, mantissaBits-exponent));
  long den=Math.round(Math.scalb(1.0, mantissaBits-exponent));
  return new BigRational(BigInteger.valueOf(man),BigInteger.valueOf(den));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

*Caveat:* Not all numbers are rational, e.g. PI is not a rational number. However, given that `double` (and `float`) have limited precision, there are a limited number of digits in a floating-point value, so you can always find a rational number for that. E.g. `Math.PI` is a `double` with the value `3.141592653589793`. That number is the rational number `3_141_592_653_589_793 / 1_000_000_000_000_000`.

Understanding the caveat that floating-point values aren't accurate, you can find the rational number with the help of `BigDecimal`, then normalize the rational number using `BigInteger.gcd()`.

Like this:

```java
static void printAsRational(double value) {
    printAsRational(BigDecimal.valueOf(value));
}
static void printAsRational(float value) {
    printAsRational(new BigDecimal(Float.toString(value)));
}
static void printAsRational(BigDecimal value) {
    BigInteger numerator, denominator;
    if (value.signum() == 0) {
        // Zero is 0 / 1
        numerator = BigInteger.ZERO;
        denominator = BigInteger.ONE;
    } else {
        BigDecimal bd = value.stripTrailingZeros(); // E.g. 1.20 -> 1.2
        if (bd.scale() < 0)
            bd = bd.setScale(0); // E.g. 1.7e3 -> 1700
        numerator = bd.unscaledValue(); // E.g. 1.25 -> 125
        denominator = BigDecimal.valueOf(1, -bd.scale()).toBigInteger(); // E.g. 1.25 -> 100
        
        // Normalize, e.g. 12/8 -> 3/2
        BigInteger gcd = numerator.gcd(denominator);
        if (! gcd.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            numerator = numerator.divide(gcd);
            denominator = denominator.divide(gcd);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(value + " = " + numerator + " / " + denominator);
}
```

*Tests*

```java
printAsRational(Math.PI);
printAsRational(Math.E);
printAsRational(1.25);
printAsRational(1);
printAsRational(0);
printAsRational(-1.25);
printAsRational(1.25e9);
printAsRational(1.25e-9);
```

*Output*

```
3.141592653589793 = 3141592653589793 / 1000000000000000
2.718281828459045 = 543656365691809 / 200000000000000
1.25 = 5 / 4
1.0 = 1 / 1
0.0 = 0 / 1
-1.25 = -5 / 4
1.25E+9 = 1250000000 / 1
1.25E-9 = 1 / 800000000
```

Comment: Question asks how to generate a numerator/denominator pair of `BigInteger` values from a given `float`/`double`, and this answer shows exactly how to do it, so why don't people like the answer? Why down-vote? What am I missing/misunderstanding here?

Comment: Hi, I think the reason is as follow: in the documentation of
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf(double)
You can read 
"""a BigDecimal whose value is equal to or **approximately** equal to the value of val."""
That is, to convert to floating point to DECIMAL notation the system may be forced to lose some precision.

Comment: @MarcoServetto But the thing is that the precision is really already lost *before* that point, given the fact that a [floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) value is an *approximation* to begin with. If you store 0.4 in a `double`, the correct answer is rational number 2/5, not what you get from not using that `valueOf()` method, which would be 3602879701896397/9007199254740992 (from `0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625`).

Comment: Of course the float is an approximation of the decimal, but once the value is in the float, that value does represents a specific number. I want to turn that exact number into a BigRational without any loss from that point on.

Comment: @MarcoServetto Which is what this code is doing, turning the *specific* number represented by a `double` into a pair of numerator/denominator `BigInteger` values, **without loss of precision**, i.e. if you convert it back to a `double`, it will be the *same value*! That is why I'm confused about the down-votes, because this is exactly what the question is asking for.