# Is there a way to decompose a floating point value at compile time?

Tags: c++, floating-point, c++20, c++23

Essentially what I need to do is to find the exact rational equivalent of a floating point value at compile-time. In other words, given `FLOAT_TYPE x` (where `FLOAT_TYPE` is any one of `float`, `double`, or `long double`), I need to extract `int64_t n` and `int16_t e` such that `x == n * pow(2.0, e)`.

I know of `frexp` (which is `constexpr` since C++23), which comes close to what I need, but it doesn't get me all the way there, as I'm not sure what the best way would be to get the fractional bit into an integer and account for that in the exponent, all in an size- and implementation-independent way.

Something that works with C++20 or earlier would be ideal, but I'd be happy to hear any solution.

PS: Infinities, NaNs, etc. can be ignored.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/51142275/5740428?

Comment: What assumptions do you make about the floating point types? That they are IEEE754? What about subnormals?

Comment: @JanSchultke That question is slightly different, as it assumes the numerator and denominator can be stored in integers, whereas I am looking for a lossless extraction of an integer and an exponent.

Comment: @user17732522 I prefer to make as few assumptions as possible. Manually dissecting IEEE encoding would only be a last resort for me. I'd prefer to rely on standard library functions as much as possible.

Comment: I don't think it makes that assumption. It stores the numerator and denominator in a `double`.

Comment: @Matt: "*the exact rational equivalent of a floating point value at compile-time*" ... that's not what "rational" means. A number is "rational" if it is expressible as the ratio of two whole numbers. That's not happening in that question.

Comment: @NicolBolas A number expressible as n*2^e is also expressible as a ratio of two integers.

Comment: @Matt: Given the numerical limitations expressed for `n` and `e`, yes, but that expression is *not* how rational numbers work. Getting the rational number equivalent of a floating point value will *not* give you `n` or `e` for your equation. The "rational" part has nothing to do with the thing you actually want. You just want the mantissa and exponent.

Comment: @NicolBolas The definition of rational numbers has absolutely nothing to do with how the number is expressed. If what you're trying to say is that floating point values are already rational numbers, then fine. But that's a bit nitpicky. The question is clear about what I am looking for.

Comment: @Matt: What I'm trying to say is that your post mentioning "rational" *at all* has nothing to do with your question. You want to extract the mantissa and exponent; this has nothing to do with rational numbers. And your confused use of "rational" is why someone suggested a different (incorrect) duplicate. You are not looking for a "rational equivalent"; you're looking for a mantissa and exponent.

Comment: @NicolBolas I see how it may come off as confusing, but my use-case actually does have everything to do with rational numbers. Extracting the significand and exponent is just the easiest way to guarantee no overflow or loss of precision in representing this particular set of rational numbers.

Comment: Apparently "mantissa" is out of fashion now, the new-fangled *in vogue* term is "significand".  I'll have to go back to college for remedial re-training.

Comment: Use `std::bit_cast` to convert the a float type to an unsigned int of the same number of bytes. Then extract the parts based on the type of float and specifiction.  You can do this at compile time since `std::bit_cast` is constexpr.

Comment: @Elijay  I'd bet most modern students who frown on saying "mantissa" instead of "significand" also couldn't explain the difference. Mathematically, a mantissa (fractional part of a logarithm, always less than 1) is a type of significand (significant digits in a scientific notation, any positive value). Floating point specifications have changed to use "significand" because it is more general.  Mantissa is still a correct (if now informal) term for a fractional significand (e.g. sum of negative powers of 2) that often is the case in real-world floating point.

Comment: @Matt, "I need to extract int64_t n and int16_t e such that x == n * pow(2.0, e)." is 
 a problem when `long double` has more significant bits than 63. [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format). `n` , as the same type as `x` always works.  Even `e` as `int16_t` may have edge concerns for tiny `x` values.  Consider a wider `e`.

Comment: @Matt A somewhat simpler approach may involve coding the FP as a hex FP constant  like +0x12300000.0p+045 in some sort of fixed width constant and then involve macro magic on a string version of it.

Comment: @Matt Why do you want " exact rational equivalent of a floating point value at compile-time. "?  It is something that FP hex constant format does not get for you?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: A FP hex constant is still a floating point. It's not about expressing it. It's about converting from floating point to a format in which I can do exact lossless multiplication and division of rational numbers at compile time. If I use a floating point, I would lose precision every time I do something like `2.0 / 3.0`.

Comment: @Matt So the goal is less of "find the exact rational equivalent of a floating point value at compile-time" and more of "exact lossless multiplication and division of rational numbers at compile time"?  In the `2.0 / 3.0` case, what division outcome do you want?